# Programatically update customer address by its entity id

Tags: magento-1.9, programmatically, customer-address, database-update

I am working on script where i display all address with respected design. Now i want to update address of user by its entity id, i have multiple array of address like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [address_line2] => 
            [postal_code] => 123456
            [web_site_id] => 18
            [country] => US
            [updated_at] => 
            [address_line1] => 45,123 apna
            [local_id] => 
            [store_id] => 20
            [customer_id] => 974
            [city] => ALBESTA
            [resource_type] => 
            [state] => Alabama
            [id] => 992
            [is_active] => 1
            [email] => test@test.com
            [phone_number] => 
            [device_model] => 
            [is_sync] => 0
            [created_at] => 
            [is_deleted] => 0
        )
)
```

In above array "id" is entity of address field. And i want to update other records of array.

Answer (score 7):

Replace this `$address->setData($addressCode, $addressData[$addressValue]);` with `$address->setData($addressCode, $addressValue);`

```
 <?php
    $addressId   = '5';
    $addressData = array(
        'postal_code' => 123456,
        'country' => 'US'
    );
    $address     = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($addressId);
    $address->setCustomerId($address->getCustomer()->getId());
    foreach ($addressData as $addressCode => $addressValue) {
        if (isset($addressData[$addressCode])) {
            $address->setData($addressCode,$addressValue);
        }
    }
    try {
        $address->setId($addressId);
        $address->save();
    }
    catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
<?php
   $addressId = '5';
$addressData = array(
    'postal_code' => 123456,
    'country' => 'US'
);
$address = Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($addressId);
$address->setCustomerId($address->getCustomer()->getId());
foreach($addressData as $addressCode => $addressValue) {
    if (isset($addressData[$addressCode])) {
        $address->setData($addressCode, $addressData[$addressValue]);
    }
}
try {
    $address->setId($addressId);
    $address->save();
} catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
    ?>
```

Comment: It is giving me error Call to a member function getStore() on a non-object in. After "$address->save();".

Comment: updated code please check

Comment: @Abdul Is there any way to update in Database?

Comment: @Gem which fields updates in database?

Comment: @Abdul How to update Customer Country in the database.